# Query many to many relationship for a user in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship, laravel-models

I have an 'Admin' model which has a manyToMany relationship with a 'Priv' model. There is a pivot table named 'admins_privs' which links the two together, as many Admin's can have many privileges.

What I need to do is to be able to do (in Blade) is to check if the logged in Admin has a certain priv (by ID) and if true, display something. I thought about adding a function in the admin model as such:

```
// Admin.php

public function HasPriv($priv_id)
{
    // Need help here!!!   
}
```

Then I can call this function in my blade templates as such:

```
// BLADE TEMPLATE

@if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()->HasPriv(1))
DO SOMETHING
@endif
```

What do i need to add into the first block of code, to search the many to many relationship to see if the user is linked to a Priv.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks M

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is related to two model, thus it has two `foreign-keys`. For your case, admins_privs table will have and `admin_id` and an `priv_id`. So, if you want to take/get specific privilege that belongs to a specific admin, you need to pass two keys (**admin_id** and **priv_id**) to controller. Or maybe take the **admin_id** inside controller from `auth()`.

***admin_controller:***

```php
public function HasPriv($priv_id,$admin_id)
{
    $pivot = DB::table('admins_privs')
            ->where(admin_id,$admin_id)
            ->where(priv_id,$priv_id)
            ->get()->first();

    return $pivot; // will be null if admin does not have the privilege
}
```